# Trigger specific branch workflow everytime when PR is created

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm new to Github action and want to trigger the master branch `.github/workflows` present in the base branch repo whenever the new PR is created.

Current Code:
`on: pull_request: branches: - "**"`

Its trigger the workflow code present in head branch and not able to fetch the secret key present in the base branch repo when PR is create from another repo.

I want to trigger the specific branch workflow for every PR created to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

The pull-request trigger for an action runs in the context of the merge commit between the head branch and the base branch. The [pull_request_target](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) trigger runs in the context of the base branch of the pull request. That seems like what you want for this action.

However, I should note that a branch on the git repo is probably not the place to store a "Secret key", take a look at Github's [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) feature for securely storing keys for use in actions workflows.